# How to create a pop up window

Tags: html, popup

Many websites have very good looking pop-up window. For example checkout
http://www.myntra.com and when you hover your mouse on any product image it shows ** Quick View ** button. I want to know how to implement this type of window. Even facebook also has good interface for sending messages. Are these types of windows different from new window. I know how to create a new window. Please tell me what are these called ? How to develop similar thing in html ?

I tried searching on net and created a sample pop window using window.open() method but this gives a different look

Comment: That's what you call a [*modal window*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). pop-ups are entirely different.

Comment: I tried searching on net and created a sample pop window using window.open() method but this gives a different look. I want to create a window which looks translucent like in these sites

Comment: The answers below are all relevant, some more technical than others, but all have 1 thing in common: You will have to use CSS to style the "window/lightbox/dialouge" to what you expect. It will most likely not be exactly what you want out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [jQuery Dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to achieve that functionality . for eg :  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ntML/)

It has a `Modal` property, you can set it to true to achieve modal dialog box

Comment: Thanks Ravi for telling me this functionality. This is cool :) I think i can proceed on my work with this..thanks a lot

Comment: accept as answer if it works for u

Answer (score 1):

This type of "window" is called a lightbox. Try looking at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ for example.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried above options but there are few problems with them like adjusting the height and width of the pop-up window, Changing some other properties also. I tried jquery dialog box and then i got an idea to create a div element and place your html content in div and you just need to set its z-index to very high level and append it to body section and see it will work as a pop up and now you can easily set up the properties for your div or pop-up. Well this works perfect for me. I used show() and hide() method whenever i wanted my pop up to be displayed. Thanks to all the above answers as they helped me solve the problem and adding to my knowledge.

Comment: Good idea..But jquery dialog box is also quite good.